# PHP nested If statement syntax

Tags: php, code

Hiya Guys! so I need some help with this:

```
            <?php

        $newsposts = new WP_Query('cat=restaurant');

        if ( is_front_page()) { echo '<h3 class="member-review">Latest Restaurants</h3>

        <div id="extra">if ($newsposts->have_posts()) : while ($newsposts->have_posts()) : $newsposts->the_post();

        <div class="reslogo"><img src="'echo catch_that_image()' /></div>

        endwhile, endif; 

        </div>';    

        } ?>
```

What I'm trying to do here is have an image slider of first post images (from restaurant category) display at the bottom of the page. I use DIVs to control placement/ style but I really need help with my PHP syntax ... I just cant figure it out... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't run code inside quote since php treats it as string, try this:

```
<?php
    $newsposts = new WP_Query('cat=restaurant');
    if ( is_front_page()) { 
        echo '<h3 class="member-review">Latest Restaurants</h3>
        <div id="extra">';
        if ($newsposts->have_posts()) : while ($newsposts->have_posts()) : $newsposts->the_post();
            echo '<div class="reslogo"><img src="'.catch_that_image().'"/></div>';
        endwhile, endif; 
        echo '</div>';    
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Hey man thank you for your suggestion I tried both approaches and found yours worked exactly as I needed - just needed to replace the endwhile, endif;  with endwhile; endif; one of these cats (;) you guys are great I really enjoy learning code and its so awesome that there are people like you out there helping guys like me ;) Cheers - ave a great sunday!

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Hi there,

Is there a way that I can limit the amount of posts being displayed? - I'd just like to have seven. I've tried this:

`code`<?php
      $newsposts = new WP_Query('cat=restaurant'.'limit=7');
      if ( is_front_page()) { 
         echo '<h3 class="member-review">Latest Restaurants</h3>
         <div id="homeslider">';
         if ($newsposts->have_posts()) : while ($newsposts->have_posts()) : $newsposts->the_post();
            echo '<div class="reslogohome"><img src="'.catch_that_image().'"/></div>';
         endwhile; endif; 
         echo '</div>';} 
   ?>`code`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a totally different syntactic approach: instead of echoing HTML from PHP, insert PHP calculated values inside HTML. This makes the code more organized and readable.

```
<?php $newsposts = new WP_Query('cat=restaurant'); ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page()): ?>
<h3 class="member-review">Latest Restaurants</h3>

<div id="extra">
    <?php if ($newsposts->have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while ($newsposts->have_posts()) : $newsposts->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="reslogo"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" /></div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>';
```

Note: I don't know if this code is correct, I just updated the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for having a look and I really liked your suggestion. Especially in your approach to the code. I appreciate your time! Have a super sunday